# Orientation change is not giving proper window height and width in PWA when launched from home screen icon in iPhone

Tags: iphone, progressive-web-apps, orientation-changes

Used sample html along with PWA. 
Added the app to home screen using safari in iPhone.

In browser whenever there is an orientation change I am able to get the proper window inner height and width, whereas in app that is launched form the home screen icon it doesn't give the changed width and height immediately in the orientation change callback.

Can someone help me with this?

Device: iPhone 12 safari

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Webkit browsers:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170595

Someone suggest:

> To avoid creating a new element, The following workaround seems to work fairly well for me:
>
> For non-Safari, get the layout viewport size from document.documentElement.clientHeight (& Width).
>
> Unfortunately, Safari's documentElement size does not update when the URL bar hides so I couldn't just apply it to all Webkit browser, but this bug just doesn't happen to Safari.